# 2 widgets in header

Tags: css, widget

I'm using the Genesis custom theme. I'm trying duplicate the header on [this site](http://www.ascseniorcare.com/), but so far all I have is [this](http://asc.ignitrodev.com/blog/).

I'm trying to create a menu for the 3 links on top of the upper nav bar, but I'm using Genesis, and there doesn't seem to be a hook to hang it on. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to include those three links and get the links in them to work? I'm truly at a loss.

Thanks in advance,

Toni

Comment: Did the answer below resolve this for you?

Answer (score 0):

Those three links have basic HTML:

```
<ul id="utility-list" class="nav-0">
    <li class="home  first-nav nav_large nav" id="utility-list_request-more-information"><a href="/request-more-information/"><span>Request More Information</span></a></li>
    <li class="home nav" id="utility-list_customer-care"><a href="/customer-care/"><span>Customer Care</span></a></li>
    <li class="home last-nav nav" id="utility-list_faq"><a href="/faq/"><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

What I would recommend is viewing the site and using the browser DevTools to help you inspect the CSS rules for each element above. That is going to tell you exactly what you need to accomplish the layout. Make sense?

Here's an example (this is the actual CSS used by http://www.ascseniorcare.com):

```
.utility-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 46px;
}

.utility-nav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: url(../css_images/senior-util-left.png) left bottom no-repeat;
    padding-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```